# composer - testing created package - class not found

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to create Hello world package with composer from this tutorial

http://grossi.io/2013/creating-your-first-composer-packagist-package/

Somehow I have managed to create it and test half day ago, but now in diferent directory I have tried again few times - cannot make it work and do not understand why I get error which I will show later.

Here is what I do:

In HelloWorld directory I create src directory.
In src directory I put file SayHello.php

```
namespace HelloWorld;

class SayHello
{
    public static function world()
    {
        return 'Hello World, Composer!';
    }
}
```

Run

```
composer init
```

After it creates composer.json file, I edit and in the end it is such:

```
{
    "name": "vagrant/hello-world",
    "description": "test",
    "license": "no",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "darius",
            "email": "darius@darius.lt"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "HelloWorld": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I run

```
composer install
```

I get output:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

Tutorial says

> Composer installed create a directory "tests" inside your root dir.

But I don't see such directory, so I create it myself in the HelloWorld directory. Maybe the author missed to add something.

Then I create file test.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'; // Autoload files using Composer autoload

use HelloWorld\SayHello;

echo SayHello::world();
```

Run:

```
php tests/test.php
```

And get:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'HelloWorld\SayHello' not found in /home/vagrant/package_dev/workbench/oitlabs/HelloWorld/tests/test.php on line 7

How can it now see it? I tried ading to test.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../src/SayHello.php';
```

then it see and works, so it means it should see the file. So its kind of like composer generates wrong autoload file or something. How can I debug this?

Also tried same steps in another directory near the one I first time succeeded, just using namespace Hello. Same error.

Here is also the file - how my package looks, what is generated by composer:
http://www58.zippyshare.com/v/Hsfg4pVf/file.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was - I needed to have directory "HelloWorld" in the src directory.

So the folder structure would look like this:

```
Root
  src
      HelloWorld
            SayHello.php
  tests
      test.php
  vendor
  composer.json
```

Comment: But anyone who knows a quicker way to debug directory structures and namespaces, are welcome to tell :)

Comment: Is it required to create the `test`  directory ??

Comment: @Jabaa - probably not, but it is useful. Usually you should have automatic tests. And also when developing, you do not need to use real project as testing environment. You run your tests from this dir and know if you implemented functionality or not.